# Running an app from Terminal with a path

Tags: go, terminal

If I can run an app (built in Go but not really necessary) like so from its own directory:

```
./some_app
```

How can I run it from a different directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to add the path to the app you are trying to run to your command. For example if the app is stored in /Users/example/apps/some_app, then you can just directly run "/Users/example/apps/some_app". You can find which directory your app is sitting in (if you are currently in that directory) with the pwd command.

Comment: Ha, so, so simple. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your app! :)

Answer (score 1):

Say you are in the home directory, and the app is under `~/app/some_app` then you can run it with `app/some_app`

If you want to be able to call it with only `some_app`, it has to be accessible in your `$PATH` variable.

In go, when you do `go install ./...` the executable will end up in `$GOPATH/bin/` which is normally part of your path if you have a correct configuration.